# Angular, cronómetro y botón con cooldown

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript, timer

Estoy tratando de crear un cronómetro que dure dos horas y cuando llegue a cero se reinicie, pero no tengo ni idea de cómo hacerlo, esto es lo que llevo:

Componente TS

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { timer } from 'rxjs';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-mantenimiento',
  templateUrl: './mantenimiento.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./mantenimiento.component.css']
})
export class MantenimientoComponent implements OnInit {
  _second = 1000;
  _minute = this._second * 60;
  _hour = this._minute * 60;
  _day = this._hour * 24;
  end: any;
  now: any;
  day: any;
  hours: any;
  minutes: any;
  seconds: any;
  source = timer(0, 1000);
  clock: any;
  constructor(){}
  ngOnInit(){
    
    this.clock = this.source.subscribe(t => {
      this.now = new Date();
      this.now.setSeconds(3600) ;
      this.end = new Date();
      this.showDate();
    });
    
  }
  showDate(){
    let distance = this.end - this.now;
    this.day = Math.floor(distance / this._day);
    this.hours = Math.floor((distance % this._day) / this._hour);
    this.minutes = Math.floor((distance % this._hour) / this._minute);
    this.seconds = Math.floor((distance % this._minute) / this._second);
  }

}
```

Código en HTML:

```
<section>
    <div class="coming-soon">
        <div class="time-countdown">
            <ul>
                {{hours}} horas
                {{minutes}} minutos
                {{seconds}} segundos
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
```

Por ahora solo he conseguido este resultado:

[image: Números negativos y cuenta regresiva negativa]

De momento solo se comporta con numeros negativos y una cuenta regresiva negativa muy extraña, necesitaria que al time.now agregarle 1 hora y así restar el tiempo actual más una hora menos el tiempo final pero aún no sé como realizarlo, agradezco su colaboración

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Es bastante sencillo al usar una biblioteca como `date-fns`.

La explicación va en comentarios.

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { interval, Subscription } from 'rxjs';
import { add } from 'date-fns';
import { takeWhile } from 'rxjs/operators';
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `{{date | date:'HH \\'Horas\\' mm \\'minutos\\' ss \\'segundos\\''}}`,
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css'],
})
export class AppComponent {
  date: Date;
  subscription$: Subscription;

  constructor() {
    this.counter();
  }

  private counter() {
    // fecha cualquiera inicializada con dos horas
    this.date = new Date('2000-01-01 02:00:00');
    // contador de las veces que el interval debe emitir
    let segundosEnDosHoras = 2 * 60 * 60;
    // interval que emite cada segundo
    this.subscription$ = interval(1000)
      // tomar un valor mientras aun queden segundos en la cuenta
      .pipe(takeWhile(() => segundosEnDosHoras-- > 0))
      .subscribe({
        // restar un segundo a la fecha actual
        next: () => (this.date = add(this.date, { seconds: -1 })),
        // cuando la cuenta termine reiniciar el contador
        complete: () => this.counter(),
      });
  }

  ngOnDestroy() {
    if (this.subscription$) {
      this.subscription$.unsubscribe();
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Me ha funcionado bien en cuestión del contador, pero cuando actualizo la página se reinicia, quisiera que no pasara eso. Mi objetivo es crear un botón el cual se active cada 2 horas